# Join two column with the same number of row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to combine 2 tables into one.  Let say I have:

Table1

```
ID       Name
1        A
2        B
3        C
```

Table2

```
ID       Name
4        D
5        E
6        F
```

I want to make Table3

```
Name1    Name2
A        D
B        E
C        F
```

How can I do this in SQL Server?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH    t1 AS
        (
        SELECT  a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
        FROM    table1 a
        ),
        t2 AS
        (
        SELECT  a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
        FROM    table2 a
        )
SELECT  t1.name, t2.name
FROM    t1
JOIN    t2
ON      t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.Name Name1, t2.Name Name2
from Table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.ID = t2.ID
```

OR

```
select t1.Name Name1, t2.Name Name2
from Table1 t1 join table2 t2
     on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: What if there is no column ID?

Comment: If there is no ID how are the tables related? What criteria determines Name1 = A corresponds to Name2 = D?

Comment: If you do not have id, use Quassnoi's solution and in the order by clauses replace id with the primary keys of your table.

Comment: As primary keys form the clustered index, so your row in Table1 will match tht in Table2